# Special characters in zsh prompt with oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, centos6, oh-my-zsh

[image: special characters on zsh prompt with oh-my-zsh]

I'm seeing some special characters after each command on zsh prompt (CentOS 6.10). I'm using oh-my-zsh and I've also installed Powerline fonts.

I'm using [spaceship-prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt) installed using [zplug](https://github.com/zplug/zplug).

Answer (score 0):

Spaceship-prompt obviously utilizes some characters the font you're using doesn't support.

The font in your screenshot is very different from the font in the OMZ screenshots.  I would guess that you installed the Powerline font that is needed, but you aren't using it.

Comment: I'm using `Fira Code` which is a Powerline font.